# Limit pictures in django model

Tags: python, django

I have working code - admin can add only 4 images in admin panel. But user also can add images in his user interface. How to do the same rules (only 4 images) for user too?

**models.py:**

```
class PicturesManager(models.Manager):
    def create_pictures(self, car, img):
        pictures = self.create(car=car, image=img)
        return pictures

class Pictures(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, verbose_name="Car", related_name='pictures')
    width = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False, default=780)
    height = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False, default=585)
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Photo", upload_to = get_file_path, max_length=64, height_field='height', width_field='width'
        )
    objects = PicturesManager()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**admin.py:**

```
class PicuresInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Pictures
    extra = 4
    # only 4 pictures
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        count = Pictures.objects.all().count()
        main = Pictures.objects.all().filter(main=True).count()
        count = Pictures.objects.filter(main=True).count()
        if count <= 4:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

So, I can copy `has_add_permission` to Pictures class and check it in views before I save images? It needs because user can edit images (delete or upload new). But in **admin.py** I use `main = True`, does it work in **model.py**?

And how to check first time, when user upload files (how many):

```
if request.FILES <= 4:
    pictures_save(car, request.FILES)
```

Right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply override the `save` method of your model, then no matter who is uploading it will restrict the images to four:

```
class Pictures(models.Model):
    # your normal fields here

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if Pictures.objects.filter(main=True, car=self.car).count() >= 4:
            return # Don't save if its already more than 4
        else:
            super(Picture, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.id)  # unicode methods should return unicode
```

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Don't think that will work, adding items via a ForeignKey doesn't involve the parent's `save` method.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid So, I can delete PicturesManager and pictures_save? And how to use this save method in views?